# Delete amazon ses template from cli

Tags: email, templates, command-line-interface, amazon-ses

How can I delete an amazon ses template using the cli?

I'm trying to use this command from the amazon doc:

```
aws delete-template --template-name xxx
```

but does not work from the cli. When I try to list all available options when I hit this command:

```
aws help
```

The delete-template is not available. I have the latest version:

```
aws-cli/1.15.79
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ses/delete-template.html

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Do you get an error message, does something crash, does it look like everything works, but the result isn't as expected?

Comment: No delete-template flag from the cli when i hit aws help to find all availaible options.

Comment: Please put that information into your question. And check whether you have the latest version of the aws tool. Maybe the tool needs a plugin to support certain commands?

Comment: I have updated my email, and also I'm using the latest version. Everything works good, created template, sending template ( from node.js) just I like to delete few test templates I have created which I've used for testing, just like to have the production one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
aws ses delete-template --template-name templateName
```

Do not add the `.json` nor `template_ prefix`.

Answer (score 7):

you are missing ses after aws in the command

`aws ses delete-template --template-name XXXX --region XXXXX`